# Printing multiple strings according to variable?

Tags: python, string

How do I go about printing a string of multiple sets of "AA"

```
if x == 1:
   print("AA")
if x == 2:
  print("AAAA")
if x == 3:
  print("AAAAAA"
```

etc..
I need a more efficient way to do it as x can be anything

Comment: Is this Python or some input file?

Comment: Its as simple as: `print('A'*x)`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is python?

```
print("AA" * x)
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work -

```
print("AA"*x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
x=int(raw_input("enter the value of 'x'"))
print ("AA"*x)
```